# Run method with reference to it's static vars from a child class

Tags: class, coffeescript

I have a class `Child` which extends `Test`. I want to call a function from `Test` from `Child`.

I tried this:

```
class Test
    constructor: ->
        @i = 'hello world'

    f1: -> console.log @i
    f2: -> console.log 'hello'

class Child extends Test
    run: ->
        Test::f1()

hello = new Child()
hello.run()
```

When I call `hello.run()`, it calls `Test.f1()`, but the result is `undefined`. It's not setting the static variable `@i` before it's running `Test.f1()`.

If I switch `Test::f1()` to `Test::f2()`, it gives me the correct result.

I need to know how should I make `Test`'s `constructor` run when I create a `new Child()` so that `@i` is defined in `Test` when I run `Test::f1()` from `Child.run()`.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
class Test
  @i: 'hello world'

  @f1: -> console.log @i
  f2:  -> console.log 'hello'

class Child extends Test
  run: ->
    Test.f1()

hello = new Child()
hello.run()
```

Notice, the `i` variable is static, so it doesn't make sense to set it in the constructor. Also, the `f1` method is now static as well.

(I'm not an expert with CoffeeScript, so I'm not sure what the `::` syntax is needed for.)

Comment: `::` is shorthand for `.prototype.`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is being run when you create a new instance of `Child`. The problem is the way that you're invoking `f1`.

You don't want to say `Test::f1()`. You can just say `@f1()`, since `Child` is a subclass of `Test`. These are different in a very important way: `Test::f1()` does not set `this`, so when that function requests `this.i`, it finds only `undefined`, because `this` is set to `Window` (or something ridiculous like that in the browser, not sure if you're running this in Node). Saying `@f1()` is the same as saying `Test::f1.call(this)`. This is one of the nice things that CoffeeScript's class system lets you do.

Finally, a pedantic note: there are no static variables in the code you've written. `i`, as you've written it, is an instance variable. Static variables look like this:

```
class Test
  @staticVar = 1234
```

Or like this:

```
class Test
  # ...

Test.staticVar = 1234
```

Instance variables look like this:

```
class Test
  fn: -> 
    @instanceVar = 1234
```

Or like this:

```
test = new Test()
test.instanceVar = 1234
```

Or even like this (for the default value of an instance variable shared among all instances):

```
Test::instanceVar = 1234
```

In a similar vein:

> When I call `hello.run()`, it calls `Test.f1()`, but the result is `undefined`. It's not setting the static variable `@i` before it's running `Test.f1()`.

You're never calling `Test.f1()`; you're calling `Test::f1()`, which is very different. In the code you've written, there *is* no `Test.f1`, only `Test.prototype.f1`.